# Grails criteria versus findAll and findAllBy benchmark

Tags: grails

I search the web and I cannot find a benchmark comparing grails criteria, findAll and findAllBy

So what is the fastest ?

```
// groovy enhance collection method
parent.childs.findAll{ it.someProperty == someValue }
```

or

```
Child.findAllByParentAndSomeProperty(parent, someValue)
```

or

```
Child.createCriteria().list{
    eq('parent', parent)
    eq('someProperty ', someValue)
}
```

**UPDATE**

As parent.childs.findAll is a groovy enhanced collection method, it dosen't call the database. Like:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].findAll{ it > 3} == [4, 5]
```

So am I better to call de DB or to loop through an already loaded collection.

Comment: Why not test it yourself?

Comment: You can enable sql output to see the queries generated. If there's a difference I think it's minimal.

Comment: I believe they will be at the same performance if they use the same query.  The bottleneck will be at the database.  If performance is important, maybe hand-write your own HQL or SQL for better control.

Comment: As parent.childs.findAll is looping on a collection, there's no DB access.

Answer (score 4):

They're all the same. That's because all of your examples are wrappers for the same underlying implementation - they're all converted to "real" Hibernate Criteria queries (or the analogous core implementation in the NoSQL library you're using) under the hood. They're all syntactic sugar.

`findAllByParentAndSomeProperty` will be a few milliseconds slower than the others the first time it's run since there's some work involved parsing the method name into criteria parameters, but dynamic finders are cached for future calls, so that's irrelevant in the general case.

But as the commenters point out, you're best off looking at the actual SQL that's run, and doing proper benchmarks when you're concerned about performance. The general case isn't applicable in every situation, and it's easy to create a query that looks like it's efficient but which generates unexpected extra database traffic and slowness.

Comment: As parent.childs.findAll is a groovy enhanced collection method, it dosen't call the database (like [1,2,3,4,5].findAll{ it > 3} == [4, 5]). So thats the whole points of my question. Am I better to call de DB or to loop through an already loaded collection. I'll update my question to be clearer